# How to create bag fast with cloth simulation?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I want to create bags from that picture:

[image]

and I think I found the fastest way:

1. create ico sphere with collision
2. create plain above it with collision and cloth simulation
3. add subdiv to plain
4. simulate
5. turn final object upside-down
6. add details (like ropes, imperfections, etc)

The problem - I'm getting something like creepy jellyfish rather than bag.
I think the problem is in cloth settings:
[image][image]

[image]

I've applied subdiv modifier with 6 iterations and solidify to plain. Can you help me to understand where the problem is? Or maybe a better way?

Comment: I would try a method similar to Blender Guru's tutorial for ruffled curtains.  Cloth pinning + shape key animation to cinch it closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the simulation with the bag upright. Pin the top, let an edge loop below shrink a bit, and place a growing *Icosphere* in it to inflate the bag.

[image: bag simulation example]

**Create the Bag**

Start with the default cube, add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with `3` levels (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>), and apply it. Add and apply a *Cast* modifier with default settings (*Sphere*) to make it more round.

Then edit the cube and delete the top faces. Select the edge loop and extrude it to create the upper part. Create a vertex group named *Pin* and assign the top edge loop. Clear selection. Create another vertex group *(Shrink*) and assign one of the lower edge loops to it.

[image: bag model]

**The Stuff (Sphere) Inside**

Place an *Icosphere* in the bag, and keyframe its *Scale* and *Location* to make it grow and move it down a little within the first 20 frames or so. You can add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and a *Displace* modifier with a *Clouds* texture to make it look edgier and more like "stuff". Finally, add a *Collision* modifier to it (must be the last/bottom).

**Bag Cloth Simulation**

Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with level `1` and a *Cloth* modifier to the bag. Set the *Pin* group for *Shape > Pin*, a low *Shrinking Factor*, and the *Shrink* group in *Property Weights > Skrinking Group*. Here also set *Max Shrinking* to `1.0` or a lower value. Then enable *Object Collisions* and *Self Collisions* and set their *Distance* value to a lower value like `0.01 m`. Run the simulation.

[image: cloth simulation]

**Post Production**

Once you're happy with the simulation **(1)** you can apply the *Subdivision Surface* and *Cloth* modifiers. In the *Sculpt* mode you can change the upper part or smooth the bag or add more wrinkles (*Cloth* brush) with the various brushes **(2)**.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it.